# In a table, select oldest records which meet some criteria and exceed, with others, a sum

Tags: sqlite

Was not easy to find an explicit and clear title. :D
My problem: I keep information about some logs stored on a NAS, in a database. I want to delete old logs when size limit is exceeded (by storage).
For example:

```
rec storage name  size    status
1     x     pip    85    discarded
2     x     foo    25    available
3     x     bla    45    available
4     x     bar    35    available
5     x     wow    50    available
5     z     sid    25    available
```

If the size limit is 100, foo and bla have to be deleted. But I don't want to delete the records from database, I just want to mark them as discarded. How do I write a single query to return that list (foo, bla in my case) and marks them as discarded? Preferable in O(n).

Comment: How should the logs be ordered? (What makes an entry an old one?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rec is an auto-generated integer primary key (And that that duplicate rec of 5 is a typo) so that the smaller the key the older the log, this approach works with Sqlite 3.25 and newer:

```
-- Create table and populate with sample data.
CREATE TABLE logs(rec INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                , storage TEXT
                , name TEXT
                , size INTEGER
                , status TEXT);
INSERT INTO logs VALUES(1,'x','pip',85,'discarded');
INSERT INTO logs VALUES(2,'x','foo',25,'available');
INSERT INTO logs VALUES(3,'x','bla',45,'available');
INSERT INTO logs VALUES(4,'x','bar',35,'available');
INSERT INTO logs VALUES(5,'x','wow',50,'available');
INSERT INTO logs VALUES(6,'z','sid',25,'available');
```

(I'm not normally a fan of using `AUTOINCREMENT` with sqlite3, but this is one case where it's called for, since it stops generated rowids from ever being reused. It's extremely unlikely that will happen without it, but let's be paranoid.)

This query computes the total size of all available logs in a particular storage category, with the total restricted to the current log and all newer (Higher rec) ones. It requires 3.25 or better because that's when window functions were added to sqlite.

```
SELECT *
     , sum(size) OVER (PARTITION BY storage
                       ORDER BY rec
                       RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       AS total_size
FROM logs
WHERE status = 'available'
ORDER BY rec;
```

produces:

```
rec         storage     name        size        status      total_size
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
2           x           foo         25          available   155        
3           x           bla         45          available   130        
4           x           bar         35          available   85         
5           x           wow         50          available   50         
6           z           sid         25          available   25
```

To get just the rows with a `total_size` column greater than 100, it has to be wrapped in a Common Table Expression because you can't use window function generated values in `WHERE` clauses:

```
WITH running_totals AS 
  (SELECT *
        , sum(size) OVER (PARTITION BY storage
                          ORDER BY rec
                          RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
          AS total_size
   FROM logs
   WHERE status = 'available')
SELECT * FROM running_totals WHERE total_size > 100 ORDER BY rec;
```

This produces:

```
rec         storage     name        size        status      total_size
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
2           x           foo         25          available   155        
3           x           bla         45          available   130
```

Which are the entries you wanted. To mark those rows as discarded, you can use a CTE with UPDATE statements too:

```
WITH running_totals AS 
  (SELECT rec
        , sum(size) OVER (PARTITION BY storage
                          ORDER BY rec
                          RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
          AS total_size
   FROM logs
   WHERE status = 'available')
UPDATE logs
SET status = 'discarded'
WHERE rec IN (SELECT rec FROM running_totals WHERE total_size > 100);
```

Comment: I get:  
near "(": syntax error: SELECT *
     , sum(size) OVER (  
- I have SQLite version 3.9.2

Comment: @Gigi Well... yeah. I mentioned the minimum version needed a few times. I have no idea how to work it out with older ones off the top of my head.